# Nuxt and Docker: specifying server in nuxt.config.js - even to default - prevents access on localhost?

Tags: node.js, docker, nuxt.js

In essence the project was setup as follows:

```
mkdir project
cd project
npx create-nuxt-app frontend
cd frontend
touch Dockerfile.development
cd ..
touch docker-compose.web.development.yml
```

In `frontend/nuxt.config.js` the following was updated:

```js
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION'

export default {
  // ... 
  server: {
    host: isDevelopment ? 'localhost' : '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost
    port: isDevelopment ? 3000 : 80, // default: 3000
  },
  // ...
}
```

In `frontend/Dockerfile.development`:

```
FROM node:10.15
ENV APP_ROOT /src

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
COPY ./frontend/package.json .
RUN npm install
```

and in `./docker-compose.web.development.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  nuxt:
    image: frontend
    container_name: nuxt_fe
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile.development
    restart: always
    environment:
      - HOST
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "npm run dev"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/assets:/src/assests
      # and then the rest of the nuxt directories
      # if I just map ./frontend:/src it will overwrite node_modules installed during build
```

If I in `nuxt.config.js` comment out the `server` configuration (even though it is set to default values), when I go to `localhost:3000` I see the site. If I uncomment `server` in `nuxt.config.js`, I see nothing.

Thought?

Comment: Can you curl the same localhost:3000 from inside the container? Does that work?

Comment: @Mihai if I `docker exec -it nuxt_fe bash` and `curl localhost:3000` I do get the `app.html` file

Comment: Your `"host"` setting must be `0.0.0.0`, or the service won't be reachable from outside its container.  From what you've shown, setting `NODE_ENV=production` should make it reachable as well.